# Open a page in Iframe from code behind Asp.net

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, iframe

Im trying to open a page in Iframe from code behind. I have added a LinkButton like this

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lbEditProject" runat="server" Text="Project Details (edit)" OnClick="lbEditProject_Click"></asp:LinkButton>
```

When OnClick event is raised, I want to open the Project Edit page which is a html page, but I want that to appear in a Iframe. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Add an iframe to your html like so:

```
<iframe sr="about:blank" id="myIFrame" runat="server" />
```

and in your onclick event:

```
myIFrame.src = "myeditpage.html"
```